# Unable to push pub/sub subscription to bigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, push, google-cloud-pubsub, endpoint

I'm trying to create pubsub push subscription to bigQuery.

This is the terraform code for the subscription with 4.14.0 version

```
provider "google" {
  region  = "europe-west1"
  version = "~> 4.14.0"
  project = var.PROJECT_ID
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "~> 4.14.0"
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  backend "gcs" {}
}
```

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "standarized_vehicles_subscription" {
  name  = var.bq_sub_name 
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.topic_standarized_vehicles.name
  
  # The push endpoint for the table
  push_config {
    push_endpoint = "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${data.google_project.project.project_id}/datasets/${var.dataset_id}/tables/${var.bq_table_id}"
  }  
}
```

I gave also the role bigquery data editor and metadataViewer to the pubsub service account

```
resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_binding" "bigquery_table_editor" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.vehicle_data_history_dataset.dataset_id
  table_id = var.bq_table_id
  role = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}

resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_binding" "bigquery_table_metadataViewer" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.vehicle_data_history_dataset.dataset_id
  table_id = var.bq_table_id
  role = "roles/bigquery.metadataViewer"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}
```

I verified that the BigQuery dataset and table are created but there is no push to the table.
I changer the URL push_endpoint to:

```
"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${data.google_project.project.project_id}/datasets/${var.dataset_id}/tables/${var.bq_table_id}/insertAll"
```

But it didn't work either.
If you could tell me what's missing i'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually want to use is a [BigQuery subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery). You are not going to be able to use a push subscription to write data directly to BigQuery. The format of the message that would be delivered to BigQuery would be [wrapped as a Pub/Sub message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receive_push), so unless you make your table match that message type, it wouldn't work. Additionally, the authentication is not going to work as you have it set up. Pub/Sub is not going to make the call with the service account for the project.

If you [look at the subscription/push_request_count metric](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_push_subscriptions), you'll be able to see the response code and why messages are getting rejected. But as I said, a BigQuery subscription would be a much better way to do this, which is also [supported in Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_subscription#example-usage---pubsub-subscription-push-bq).

Comment: Thank you for your response , indeed i change the push_config block with bigquery_config and i updated the provider version to 4.32.0 because this feature is first included in this version. i tested and it worked.